# Is it possible to compute arguments to `\put` from variables when using overpic?

Tags: calculations

Consider the following example (substitute any image).

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\numberLeftOffset}{3}
    \newcommand{\numberTopOffset}{7}
    \newcommand{\numberSuitOffset}{7}

    \begin{overpic}[width=2.5 in,grid,tics=10]{images/Strike.jpg}
        \put (7,93) {foobar} 
         \put (7,87) {barfoo} 
    \end{overpic}

%    \begin{overpic}[width=2.5 in,grid,tics=10]{images/Strike.jpg}
%        \put (\numberLeftOffset,\numexpr(100 - \numberTopOffset) \relax) {foobar} 
%         \put (\numberLeftOffset,\numexpr(100 - \numberTopOffset  - \numberSuitOffset) \relax ) {barfoo} 
%    \end{overpic}
\end{document}
```

In the lines that are currently commented out, I am trying to compute the arguments to `\put` based on variables that are set above. However, this fails with the following error.

```
! Missing ) inserted for expression.
<to be read again> 
                   \unitlength 
l.16 ...et,\numexpr(100 - \numberTopOffset) \relax
                                                  ) {foobar}
```

What is the correct way to compute arguments to `\put`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put braces around the expression. Otherwise, TeX takes the closing parenthesis in the expression as the closing parenthesis for `\put`.

```
\begin{overpic}[width=2.5 in,grid,tics=10]{images/Strike.jpg}
    \put (\numberLeftOffset,{\numexpr(100 - \numberTopOffset) \relax}) {foobar} 
    \put (\numberLeftOffset,{\numexpr(100 - \numberTopOffset  - \numberSuitOffset) \relax}) {barfoo} 
\end{overpic}
```

By the way, in this case, the parentheses are useless in the expression.